# How to deal with exotic boundary conditions for Wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I'm currently trying to solve a PDE, the problem is as follows:
Solve the equation $\frac{\partial ^{2} u}{\partial t^{2} } = c^{2}\frac{\partial ^{2} u}{\partial x^{2} }$ on the semi-infinite interval $0<x<L$ and with the conditions
$$u_{x} + \alpha u \bigg |_{x=0} = 0 $$
$$f(x) = u \bigg |_{t=0} = \delta(x- x_{0}) \qquad and \qquad g(x) = u _{t}\bigg |_{t=0} = c\delta'(x- x_{0})$$

As far as I know, d'alembert solution should work to satisfy the initial conditions f and g, but I don't know how to deal with the boundary conditions.

If I have a general form for u, how would I apply this kind of boundary condition?

Comment: what if you had $u\mid_{t=0}(x) = h(x)$ and $u_t\mid_{t=0}(x) = c \, h'(x)$ ?

Comment: There would be a particular solution term which would be $\frac{1}{2c} \int _{x-ct}^{x+ct} h(x) dx$ right? @user1952009

Comment: Définitions of $\delta$ and $\delta'$ are missing.

Comment: @JJacquelin They are the dirac-delta function with impulse at $x_{0}$.

Comment: What is $x_0$  compared to $0$ and to $L$ ? Why is there no boundary condition at $x=L$ ?